# Datagrid Eval value check if 0

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid

I have a Datagrid that has a TemplateColumn there I have a  label that's contains data on bind. I all ready have a public method for it that checks something in it now i want to check if the value that's inside that row is 0 if it is 0 make it blank. Here is the code.

aspx

```
    <asp:datagrid id="dgData"  runat="server" Width="658px" CellPadding="2" PageSize="2" DataKeyField="ItemDataID"
                AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowFooter="True" BorderColor="AliceBlue" OnItemDataBound="dgData_ItemDataBound">
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Term 1" ItemStyle-Wrap="True">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:label BorderStyle=None Visible='<%# ReverseBool(Convert.ToBoolean(DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.IsCompleteOrNot"))) %>' runat="server" ID="edit_Score" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Score") %>'>
                            </asp:label>
                            <asp:label BorderStyle=None Text='<%# GetCompleteIncomplete(Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Number"))) %>' Visible='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.IsCompleteOrNot") %>' id="txtIsComplete" runat="server">
                            </asp:label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateColumn>
```

c# the GetCompleteIncomplete method

```
 protected string GetCompleteIncomplete(int iNumber)
    {

        if (iScore == 0)
        {
            return "Incomplete";
        }
        return "Complete";
    }
```

How can I check if the value for that Number is 0 
Thanks in Advance best regards :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ternary operator to set the visibility inline.

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" 
   Visible='<%# Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Number")) == 0 ? false : true %>' Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Number") %>'></asp:Label>
```

Comment: Didn't get it What you want me to do set another label that has ID ? i need thoes DataItemScore and IsCompleteotNot beside removing them any other method ? and when i try to put in the == 0 it says == not allowed in between string and int

Comment: `id` is just the column name for this snippet, you should change it to your own. But your question states that the item is left blank if it is `0`. That is what this does, hide the label when the value is `0`. Or do we not understand each other?

Comment: Sorry its me i am not understanding So you see the Label where it says DataItem.Score that line should be the one blank if the value of it that comes from database is 0 now to set that to blank upon its being 0 you said put in the line  == 0 ? false : true when i do that i get a Error saying Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'int'

Comment: I've updated. Maybe in your case you need to use `DataBinder.Eval`, not `Eval`

Comment: Ok could you tell me which one of the above 2 Labels i have should i replace with this one ?